# Javascript: How to retrieve a value from a popup after a click event is fired

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page where clicking on a link will open a popup window. The popup window will contain some value. Now when user clicks on a div tag, I want to copy the text of that div into a text box of the main window.

I have used following code to open a popup -

```
popup = window.open(location, "popup","menubar=1,resizable=1,scrollbars=1,width=650,height=450");
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `opener` to reference the parent window from your child window.  [Here's an example](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_opener.asp) from W3 Schools...

... and here's a working example from me:

***Parent Window***

**Script**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $().ready(function () {
                $('#link').click(function (e) { 
                    e.preventDefault();  
                    window.open("popup.htm"); 
                });
        });
        function updateContent(content) {
            $('#contentHolder').html(content);
        }
        </script>
```

**HTML**

```
<a id="link" href="popup.htm" target="_blank">Open Window</a>
<div id="contentHolder"></div>
```

***Child Window***

**Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function () {
        $('#contentDiv').click(function () {
            window.opener.updateContent($(this).html()); 
        });
    });
    </script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="contentDiv">Clickable Div</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You tagged your question as jquery. There is one thing to look out for, if you want to use jquery inside the pop-up from the main window. It works something like this:

```
window.opener.$(selector, window.opener)
```

So, you are using the jquery of the pop-up and specify a context as well (2nd parameter). I am not completely sure, that 2nd step is necessary as well.

Comment: it works the other way around as well of cours, i.e. `popup.$(selector, popup)`